# Not repeating handler function in React JS

Tags: reactjs, dry

I currently have the following code in a number of modules:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const id = target.id;

    this.setState({
        [id]: value
    });
}
```

I am trying to consolidate my code so that I am not repeating myself. I was originally trying to move this file to another file called FormHandler.js and place this code into a class called FormHandler. I would then import the handler as follows:

```
Import FormHandler from '.\FormHandler
```

I think I would then be able to use it like this:

```
<input id="first_name" onChange={FormHandler.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

The main problem I am trying to get my mind around is with the setting the state. Currently, it would try to set the state in the FormHandler class rather than the component that I am calling it from.

So, two questions:

1. Should I bother with trying to separate this code into its own module so that I am not repeating myself? After all the `import` command is itself a type of repetition.
2. If so, how do I go about getting it to update the state of the calling component. It seems anything I can come up with is just causing more repetition.

Answer (score 0):

One potential idea could be to pass a state handler function as defined in your component into the generic change handler.

This state handler would then be called after all your logic has been completed, with your `value` and `id` as arguments.

**formHandler.js**

```
export default function handleChange(stateHandler){

  return event => {

    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const id = target.id;

    stateHandler(id, value);
  };
}
```

**yourComponent.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import handleChange from './formHandler';

export default Comp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  stateHandler(id, value) {
    this.setState({
      [id]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <input id="test-input" onChange={handleChange(this.stateHandler.bind(this))} />;
  }
}
```

On render, the handleChange function will be executed, itself returning a function which will ultimately call the stateHandler when the onChange event is triggered on the input.

Answer (score 0):

For state management, I strongly advise to look into `redux` and `redux-form` libs instead of trying to build something of your own. They provide some very flexible ways to setting up a so-called `store` for app's state management. This way, the state is not dependent on any internal component's implementation as in your case, for example.

As for answering your code duplication question, one way I'd see a solution to it is to have a `FormHandler` or `FormEventHandler` (the latter sounds better for me as it's more explicit, but that's subjective) class being inherited from another class.

Then, in any component where you need `FormHandler`'s `handleChange` method, you can implement into your component's class with `extend` to access the shared methods, like:

```
class InputArray extends FromEventHandler { }
```

Personally, I still prefer the explicit usage of `FormHandler` because it's easier to track instead of class inheritance. In the long term, when a class starts inheriting from multiple other classes, it starts being confusing to track down which contains what. Not to mention, there's always a chance that `FormHandler` and `EventDistributor` can have the same methods like `handleChange`, so inheriting from both classes may introduce some interesting results instead of using their `handleChange` the import way. (`EventDistributor.handleChange`, etc.)